# Arithmetic operation on string

Tags: python, math, sequence, delimiter, difference

I have a string . It looks like:

```
00:00:08
00:40:20
01:50:20
.....
```

and so on.

In the first line , 00 is the hour , next 00 is minute and 08 is seconds. I need to get the total seconds. I am trying to split the string and multiply the 1st element with 3600, 2nd element with 60 and keep the 3rd element as it is. So, for 1st line it will be 00*3600 + 00*60 + 08. But whenver I am tring to multiply instead of multiplication it is doing iteration.

```py
if ':' in entry:
    t = entry
    # print(t)
    for item in t:
        t1,t2,t3 = t.split(":") 
        print(t1,t2,t3)
        hour.append(int(t1))
        hour1 = hour*3600
        minute.append(int(t2))
        minute1 = minute*60
        second.append(int(t3))
        second1 = second
```

But this is not working. Could you give some idea ?

Thank you.

Described in previous section.

Comment: Never say that code "isn't working", [say what it does, and how that's different from expectation](/help/how-to-ask). "It's not working" is not a problem description, it's an opinion, so explain the motivation behind that opinion (because the code, of course, works exactly the way you wrote it to work).

Answer (score 0):

1. first you can get the time str from origin str

```
    s = """
    00:40:20
    01:50:20
    """
    ss = [t.strip() for t in s.split("\n") if t.strip() != ""]
    print(ss)
```

which output

```
['00:40:20', '01:50:20']
```

2. then you can use the timedelta in package datetime to get the seconds

```
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    delta = datetime.strptime(ss[1], "%H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(ss[0], "%H:%M:%S")
    print(delta.seconds)
```

you will get

```
4200
```

Answer (score 0):

The datetime module has functionality that will help with this problem. However, if you don't want to use any of that (e.g, strptime) then you can write your own custom function.

Here's code that uses a custom function and datetime functionality to achieve the same objective

```
from collections.abc import Iterator
from datetime import datetime

s = """\
00:40:20
01:50:20
"""

def total_seconds(s: str) -> int:
    def _tsg(s: str) -> Iterator:
        for n, m in zip(s.split(':'), [3600, 60, 1]):
            yield int(n) * m
    return sum(_tsg(s))

print('Using custom function')
for line in s.splitlines():
    print(line, total_seconds(line))

epoch = datetime(1900, 1, 1)
print('\nUsing datetime module')
for line in s.splitlines():
    d = datetime.strptime(line, '%H:%M:%S')
    print(line, int((d-epoch).total_seconds()))
```

**Output:**

```
Using custom function
00:40:20 2420
01:50:20 6620

Using datetime module
00:40:20 2420
01:50:20 6620
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the simplest way with Basic Python then just split on the NewLine, then split on the colon and do the calculation:

```
s = '''
00:40:20
01:50:20
'''

for t in s.strip().split('\n'):
    nums = t.split(':')
    secs = int(nums[0])*3600 + int(nums[1])*60 + int(nums[2])
    print(secs)
```

gives

```
2420
6620
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look the built-in module [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), use `datetime.strptime` to parse the string and get the time-quantities that you need.

```
from datetime import datetime


def str2seconds(s):
    # parse the string and convert as seconds
    dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%H:%M:%S")    
    return sum(t*60**i for i, t in enumerate((dt.second, dt.minute, dt.hour)))


str_times = """
00:00:08
00:40:20
01:50:20
""".strip('\n')

# apply the conversion to each
print(*map(str2seconds, str_times.splitlines()), sep='\n')
#2420
#6620
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the strings to integers first.

For example, this code: `print("1" * 5)` will output "11111" instead of "6".

This code should work:

```
timeString = """
02:11:59
11:34:06
"""

times = timeString.splitlines()

for time in times:
    if ":" in time:
        timeList = time.split(":")
        seconds = 3600 * int(timeList[0]) + 60 * int(timeList[1]) + int(timeList[2])

        print(seconds)
```